# Check response time with HTTPWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to find the performance of some of my proxies. I tried the `Ping` class in .net but it does not accept ports. Is there a way to check how long a response took with `httpwebrequest`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

timer.Start();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close ();

timer.Stop();

TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
```

Comment: This is inaccurate if there is a delay starting up the backing thread. I have run into this where there is a delay between when you ask for the request and when it is actually made. This is very noticeable if you try to stress test something with multiple simultaneous HttpWebRequests. This is because of the backing ThreadPool.

Comment: How to do in a loop? `foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                { ........ }`

Answer (score 19):

Why not just time it from the client side?

```
WebRequest request = BuildRequest();
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    // Potentially fetch all the data here, in case it's streaming...
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Request took {0}", sw.Elapsed);
```

Comment: This is inaccurate if there is a delay starting up the backing thread. I have run into this where there is a delay between when you ask for the request and when it is actually made. This is very noticeable if you try to stress test something with multiple simultaneous HttpWebRequests. This is because of the backing ThreadPool.

Comment: @Xenophile: Which "backing thread"? None of the code shown *does* start a new thread. There's a *connection* pool which (by default) will only allow four concurrent connections to the same host - is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: My understanding was that an io thread is spawned/consumed and it still listens for a completion event even if it is called synchronously. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683(v=VS.85).aspx so in a stress test, you may have to wait for the io thread to start which will cause inaccurate timing. I could be wrong, this is not my area of exertise.

Comment: @Xenophile: I don't know the exact details behind IO completion ports, but I think the connection time is *much* more likely to be significant. Compared with the cost of setting up a TCP connection, the cost of creating a thread is very small - and the threads are pooled anyway.

Comment: @Xenophile: Besides, what do you mean by "inaccurate"? If there's a delay in setting it up in the test, presumably there would be a similar delay from "real" client code. A client-side test can only ever test complete round-trip time properly, of course.

Comment: If I am trying to stress test a service.  Say I open 100 requests 10ms apart and look at the response times. If the requests are long running  you will hit a point where you exceed the Minimum configured IO threads that the CLR Threadpool contains (default 1 per processor?). The threadpool then will insert a 500ms delay between IO thread starts. With a service that takes 4000ms, this test with default Min IO Threads(4 in my case) averages 14000ms, with using ThreadPool.SetMinThreads set IO thread min to 100, it takes 4085ms. These are different threads than where the WebRequest objects live.

Comment: @Xenophile: Stress test or performance test? They're very different. But yes, if you want to test lots of concurrent connections, you need to perform some appropriate tweaks - setting the number of concurrent connections allowed as well as potentially the number of IO completion ports. I think that's reasonable.

Comment: OK, which timer should I use to measure request time in performance tests   if I use `HttpWebRequest::HttpWebRequest` ?

Comment: @hellboy: You'd use `Stopwatch`, as per my answer. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking...