# How to capture web method debug lines programmatically in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I have a .NET application that is using the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client package to get data from TFS server.

When I run my app in Visual Studio 2017 I see the following information in the Output console:

```
Web method running: [http://mytfsserver/tfs/Site/_apis/git/repositories/<repoId>/items?scopePath=%2FMobile.AuthenticationService%2FMobile.AuthenticationService.Tests%2F&recursionLevel=Full&download=False&version=Release] (GET)items[git]
Web method response: [http://mytfsserver/tfs/Site/_apis/git/repositories/<repoid>/items?scopePath=%2FMobile.AuthenticationService%2FMobile.AuthenticationService.Tests%2F&recursionLevel=Full&download=False&version=Release] (GET)items[git] 206 ms
```

I'm trying to troubleshoot a performance issue where my same app in the server takes twice the time to execute a report than locally and would like to capture the request response times as shown at the end of the second response debug message.

Is there a way to capture those debug lines programmatically? I know I can use fiddler but I don't think i have permissions to install it in my web server.

Here is a link of existing VSTS REST API debug output behavior: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/263288/please-optionally-remove-web-method-running-and-we.html

Here is a sample call that would result in such output:

```
var changeset = versionControlServer.ArtifactProvider.GetChangeset(new Uri(externalLink.LinkedArtifactUri));
```

Comment: What about using a timer, as demonstrated in this post [Check Response Time with httpwebrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893897/check-response-time-with-httpwebrequest)?

Comment: The problem is that the TFS api is making the requests internally. Those debug lines come from inside the library. I'm thinking about using a Trace listener like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159755/where-does-system-diagnostics-debug-write-output-appear

Comment: Without looking at the code it's hard to understand, but couldn't you start the timer before handing off to the API and then stop it once the response is received?

Comment: I put a sample request in my original post. I could try wrapping my calls in a timer. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Just try the Diagnostics Tools -  `Network ` tool in VS, see [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/05/04/introducing-visual-studios-network-tool/) for details. Hope that helps.

Comment: @AdolfoPerez Have you resolved the issue? any update?